# PHP Scraped content loading at the bottom

Tags: php, html

Please consider the following code for a web page:

```
<?php
    $output = file_get_contents($url);
    $start = strpos($output, "<table");
    $end = strpos($output, "</table>");
    $table = substr($output, $start, ($end - $start));
    echo($table);
 ?>

!!!!!!!!
```

I would have expected the page to load in this order, however it appears to be loading as:

```
!!!!!!!

Table from URL
```

Now I understand that pulling content from another URL will take longer than simply rendering some '!!!!'s, but as PHP runs server side and I believe runs synchronously I cannot explain why this happens. If someone can explain the situation, and suggest a fix for this, I'd be appreciative.

**Edit:**
I am now getting around this by doing some Jquery to reshuffle the order of divs on document ready. It feels very hacky and I don't like it, but for now it'll have to do. If someone can find a better solution, please do let me know.

Comment: This is return html of given url, You should find usable data from html code.

Comment: This is help to find usable data http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi Irfan, thanks for that, but isn't that just a wrapper for some regex? If so I don't know if that would have effect on the order in which it loads? (I may very well be wrong)

Comment: I'm unable to understand your situation

Comment: Okay, no prob :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Interesting problem. If you replaced your PHP code by a simple `echo('hello');`, does it do the same? Also: have you checked the source of the generated file? is the order reversed there, too?

Comment: Echoing hello works as expected, it seems to have something to do with the table. If I die() straight after echoing the table, then have the rest of the HTML code, it still loads the HTML after the die. Also the table seems to be working normally on the page I am loading it from

Comment: I *think* the browser is trying to be clever and loading the rest of the HTML asynchronously alongside the php generated echoed HTML and in its infinite wisdom deciding to put it after everthing :\

Comment: Did you check the HTML source code in the browser? There lies the truth. If everything you presented in the question is contained in a single PHP script then there is no such thing as *"loading the rest of the HTML asynchronously"*.

Comment: I checked the code in the browser yes, and the !!!!!!'s (or indeed whatever HTML element I put here, <h1>'s etc etc) were above the table. Everything you see there in the question, is within index.php (Except for the $url, as this is replaced by the actual URL being used as a string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because [the result of the scraped output](https://3v4l.org/dSevk) of the HTML does not include the closing `</table>` tag.

I can't find any specs describing the following behaviour, but I suspect the browser is unable to determine if the `====` belongs to the `table` or the `body` and so has prepend it to the inner HTML of the `body`.

To fix this, include the length of that closing table tag (8 characters)

```
$table = substr($output, $start, ($end - $start + strlen('</table>')));
```

Comment: Agree, the output HTML should contain the closing </table> tag.

Comment: Doh!, how could I miss such a simple error :) hah.
Thanks, I will award bounty as soon as I can